# Issues with build.phonegap write to file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build a [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) application through the [online build service](https://build.phonegap.com) that should run on both [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) and [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), but this question focuses on the Android part.

The main target of the application is to be able to access and modify the filesystem.
Inspired from [Raymond Camden's blog post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/9/PhoneGaps-File-API), I ended up writing a sample application very similar to his, that accesses the filesystem with read/write privileges. The main difference is that my application is built online without any SDK installed and without caring about any *androidManifes.xml* file.

My **problem** is that I am able to access the filesystem (list directories, read files), but I am not able to write anything on it.

I have included the [necessary `<feature />` tag in the *confix.xml*](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) in order to have file access permissions:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

Here is some sample code used in my application:

#### Read file code:

```
// Request fileSystem
fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create:true}, readFile, onError);

// Function that reads a file
function readFile(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.log("contents: ", e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

#### Write/append file code:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create:true}, function(file){
    file.createWriter(function(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function() {
            console.log('writing', arguments);
        }

        writer.onerror = function(e) {
            console.error('error', e);
        }

        writer.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log('writeend', arguments);
        }

        //Go to the end of the file...
        writer.seek(writer.length);

        // Append a timestamp
        writerOb.write("Test at "+new Date().toString() + "\n");
    })
}, onError);
```

The second code sample doesn't write anything in the targeted file and the `onerror` handlers shows that it's because of a `NOT_FOUND_ERR`. And this just doesn't make sense, because I am able to read that same file (and it can be *found*).

In the same manner, when I try to create a new file (with the same code from *write/append file code*, but where the targeted file doesn't exist), I get a `INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR` error.

I have also tried [the example in the official documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader_full_example) and I got the same result (read and no write).

Note that since PhoneGap is using the HTML5 file [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), I've tried to write the contents through [blobs](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) as suggested in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685020/how-to-create-a-text-file-locally-at-client-side-using-javascript-jquery) (and in other sites) without any luck.

What am I missing? Do I need a separate plugin for writing files or is this something that can't be done via the online build tool and I have to download the SDK and compile the application the old fashioned way?

P.S.: My PhoneGap version is **2.3.0**.

Comment: Does the phone have an SD card? Also does it work if you compile in the normal manner?

Comment: @Warpzit yes, the phone has an SD car and the targeted file was on it; and NO, I only tried it through build.phonegap.com

Comment: What is the actual value of fileName ? Are you trying to write on the root or on a subdirectory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created [an app](https://github.com/uw-ictd/freespeech) with PG build that writes to the file system, so I'm certain it can be done and doesn't require a plugin. The main conspicuous difference I'm seeing in my code is that I'm explicitly setting the exclusive flag in the getFile options to false.

If you're testing with iOS another shot in the dark solution would be to check that you're setting your app id correctly in the config.xml

EDIT: In the app I mentioned, there file system writing code is [here](https://github.com/UW-ICTD/FreeSpeech/blob/638994d5799ad26abdfa8cd416339b205d27b0df/boilerplate/libs/sfsf/sfsf.js#L110)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Java method I'm using for writing to a file:

```
public void writeMyFile(String fileName, String data) throws IOException {

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    System.out.println(root);
    File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    String[][] recordvalue = new String[100][100];
    System.out.println("fetched value" + data);
    String[] line = data.split("#");

    // I had multiple lines of data, all split by the # symbol in a single string.
    System.out.println("row length "+line.length);

        for (int i=1; i<line.length; i++)
        {
            writer.append("#");
            recordvalue[i] = line[i].split(",");
            for(int j=0; j<recordvalue[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(recordvalue[i][j]);
                writer.append(recordvalue[i][j]);
                writer.append(",");
            }
            writer.append("\n");
        }

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(gpxfile);
    System.out.println(uri);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    try {
        // Do something
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // If there is nothing that can send a text/html MIME type
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The imports for the class/method are as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
```

And the main execute class for the plugin is as follows:

```
public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
    try {
         String fileName = arg1.getString(0);
         String data = arg1.getString(1);
         writeMyFile(fileName, data);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Provide the solution for his issue instead of suggesting another way. And Also this can be posted as a comment.

Comment: It is the solution. The code he's using is a tiny part of my code. I'm basically giving him all the parts that he's missing to ensure he has the whole working code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you call [requestFileSystem](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileSystem) the proper way and after the device is ready

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, yourCode, fail);
}
```

Second, make sure *fileName* is only the name of a file without path, if you want to use directories, you should use [DirectoryEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry).

Comment: that is exactly how I'm requesting the file system, and as I said, I can access (read) the file

Comment: Is fileName a file name or a path ? I remember having problem using file paths and it wouldn't surprise me if it works for reading but not for writing.