# Creation of a text file from Javascript (or any other way) on the client side?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a text file from Javascript. The user will submit a form, the form will have multiple choices. The user will select the appropriate answers and click on submit button. Now these answers will be put in that text file. For designing this, I have created the HTML file. Now I have a problem with the Javascript. Please tell me, is there any other way instead of JavaScript?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178825/create-text-file-in-javascript

Comment: the other way is to use server-side script, e.g. PHP

Comment: Why do you want to create a text file.

Comment: Why do you need the text file? Is it just to provide some persistence, or will there be other content? For persistence you can use localStorage or the filesystem API. If you're trying to provide a document that the user can access outside the browser you will have to send it via a server.

Comment: @Vinay: I'm not sure that the answers on that one are that great or current. I figure if there's not a better question more recent it might be worth the revisit.

Comment: @Parakrant: if you are only interested in WebKit browsers, this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685020/how-to-create-a-text-file-locally-at-client-side-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: thanks guys for comment. Special thanks to @JayC,@vladkras,@Mike W. Since i am new to web technology. I wanted to know about alternative ideas to implement this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a *String* of whatever text you want

```
var str = 'Hello world!';
```

1. Create a [*Blob*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with *MIME* type of *text/plain*

```
var b = new Blob([str], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

2. Generate a URL from your *Blob*

```
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(b);
```

3. Point your user to it in your favourite way, e.g.

```
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```

OR, if you want to download this

```
var a = document.createElement('a'),
    e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  // simulated click
e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.setAttribute('href', fileURL);
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');           // fallback behaviour
a.setAttribute('download', 'myTextFile.txt'); // file name
a.dispatchEvent(e);                           // download
```

Comment: @downvoter please explain why you've down voted this answer; it creates a text file in _JavaScript_ in the client's browser, as requested.