# Create a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a text file in javascript. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 var file_name=dir+'/aaa.txt';
 var fso = CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
 var s = fsoo.CreateTextFile(file_name, True);
 s.Close();
```

I need to create an empty file to a path.

UPDATE1:
I have also tried this, but doesn't work. Also I can not import System.IO:

```
 var file_name='aaa.txt';
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file_name);
 sw.WriteLine("This is the line");
 sw.Close();
```

UPDATE2:
I also have tryed to execute a unix comand that does 'touch file_name'. However this doesn't work either:

```
 var sys = require('sys')
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var child;

 child = exec(\"touch\" + file_name, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
    sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
       console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
 });
```

Does anyone know how I should create a file in javascript?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create a Text File Locally at client side using JavaScript/JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685020/how-to-create-a-text-file-locally-at-client-side-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Do you want to do this with a browser, and to write to the local filing system? The browser security model will stop you doing that, if so.

Comment: Are you attempting to run this in a browser? Or in server-side Javascript, in Node for example?

Answer (score 0):

This project on github looks promising:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

> FileSaver.js implements the W3C saveAs() FileSaver interface in
>   browsers that do not natively support it.

Also have a look at the demo here:

http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: As I see this helps if you want to download(save locally) some file. I only need to create a file on a specific path (similar to touch file in batch).

Answer (score 0):

**Node.js has a library called *FS***
[FS Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/create-file-in-nodejs-using-node-fs-module/)

You can easily create files using a built in function as so,

```js
// include node fs module
var fs = require('fs');
 
// writeFile function with filename, content and callback function
fs.writeFile('newfile.txt', 'Learn Node FS module', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File is created successfully.');
});
```